# nginx proxy_pass could not be resolved (3: Host not found)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

#### I have the following nginx configuration which returns 502

```
server {
    listen      2052;
    listen      2082;
    server_name good.abc.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://goodServer:$server_port;
    }
}
```

#### Testing:

`proxy_pass http://goodServer:2052;` When the fixed port is `2052`

`curl good.abc.com:2052` It can be accessed normally.

#### Question:

The port I want to forward user requests to

For example.

```
curl good.abc.com:2052 ---> goodServer:2052
curl good.abc.com:2082 ---> goodServer:2082
```

So the port must be a variable, just like `$server_port`

#### Log:

```
2021/04/04 14:10:11 [error] 24#24: *19 good could not be resolved (3: Host not found), client: 162.158.91.119, server: good.abc.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "good.abc.com:2052"
```

Comment: Use two different server directives and you wont need variable.

Comment: I have a lot of ports

Comment: What is the error? Check the error logs. You probably need to [define a `resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).